# How to use "I am the one"

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

Is it correct to say the following?

> "I think I am the one who did it"

> Let's say In the past I created some article. But not sure whether I really created it or not. And at the same time there is no one else to create that article. So if some one ask me "did u create it"  I want to convey I did it but not 100% sure.

I see 2 ways in which I can answer

1. I think I am the one who did it.
   2 I should be the one who did it

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to tell us more about which words in the phrase you're unsure about and why. You offer two options, contrasting "think" and "should," but I'm more interested in why you're using "... the one" in the first place. Can you say more about that?

Comment: The situation is very strange.  How could you not know if you wrote an article or not!?

Answer (score 1):

There's no mistake in "I think I am the one who did it".

However "I think I did" is shorter and has much the same meaning, in context.

If someone asks "Did you create it", then "I think I did", or "I think so" would be the normal way to express the idea that you are not 100% sure.

Answer (score -1):

Choosing between your two options, this one is better:

> I think I am the one who did it.